# type casted call to postgres stored procedure not matching

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure via pgAdmin, logged in as 'postgres' (the only user, and an admin):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."spCreateMeet"(
    "_MeetName" character varying,
    "_MeetBannerDescription" character varying,
    "_MeetDate" date)
LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
INSERT INTO public."tblMeet"
("MeetName", "MeetBannerDescription", "MeetDate")
VALUES ("_MeetName", "_MeetBannerDescription", "_MeetDate")
RETURNING "MeetId";
$BODY$;
```

Here's my call, being made directly in pgAdmin, logged in as same user that created it:

```
CALL spCreateMeet('TestMeet'::character varying,'blah'::character varying,'2021-06-01T00:00:00.000Z'::date)
```

It is properly type cast, and I've tried qualifying with 'public.', so why am I getting:

```
ERROR:  procedure spcreatemeet(character varying, character varying, date) does not exist

LINE 1: CALL spCreateMeet('TestMeet'::character varying,'blah...
             ^

HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't use upper case or camel case in column, table, function etc. names in postgresql because it is case sensitive. If you do that then it will create a problem every time.

you can see the error where it is showing the procedure name in small case. If you will not surround the names with double quote then it will treat it as small case only so the solution is surround the names with double quote.

Try this:

```
CALL "spCreateMeet"('TestMeet'::character varying,'blah'::character varying,'2021-06-01T00:00:00.000Z'::date)
```

Comment: I'm just learning Postgres, so this was news to me how case sensitive it is, however, I'm too far down the rabbit hole with this project to refactor my whole database to be all lowercase. at this point, I like having to put all defined objects in quotes because it helps keep things straight if I have column names and variables with the same names. Call me crazy.

TIL I also shouldn't have been using stored procs. Coming from a SqlServer and Oracle background, I'm used to stored procedures being able to return datasets. So I did a fair amount of refactoring anyway. Thanks for your help!